# Get maximum, minimum values across columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I want to get the minimum and maximum across multiple columns in a row. I found various working queries using CROSS APPLY, UPIVOT and VALUES, e.g. like this one:

```
select column1, column2, code1,
       (qty2), (qty3), (qty4), (qty5),
       MinVal, MaxVal 
from dummydata 
    cross apply (select MIN(NULLIF (d ,0)) MinVal, 
                        Max(d) MaxVal 
                 FROM (VALUES (qty2), 
                              (qty3), 
                              (qty4), 
                              (qty5)
                      ) AS a(d) 
                )  A
```

These all are working in SQL Server 2005 or above, but I need a solution for SQL Server 2000 (database compatibility level 80). How can I do that?

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dummydata](
[column1] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[column2] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[code1] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[qty2] [float] NULL,
[qty3] [float] NULL,
.......
[qty20] [float] NULL)
```

Query output:

[image]

Comment: Simplest solution: upgrade.

Comment: Are the columns 4 or more?

Comment: dear ,  20 columns

Answer (score 5):

It's not going to be pretty (and I have no 2000 installation to test) but this should work.

The `pk` is the `PRIMARY KEY` of the table (or a column with `UNIQUE NOT NULL` constraints):

```
SELECT d.column1, d.column2, d.code1,
       d.qty2, d.qty3, d.qty4, d.qty5, ..., d.qty20,
       m.MinVal, m.MaxVal 
FROM 
    dummydata AS d 
  JOIN
    ( SELECT q.pk,
             MIN(NULLIF(q.qty, 0)) AS MinVal, 
             MAX(q.qty) AS MaxVal 
      FROM 
        ( SELECT pk, qty2 AS qty FROM dummydata UNION ALL
          SELECT pk, qty3 FROM dummydata UNION ALL
          SELECT pk, qty4 FROM dummydata UNION ALL
          SELECT pk, qty5 FROM dummydata UNION ALL
          ...
          SELECT pk, qty20
        ) AS q
      GROUP BY pk
    ) AS m
    ON m.pk = d.pk ;
```

Alternative is to use correlated subqueries in the `SELECT` list:

```
SELECT d.column1, d.column2, d.code1,
       d.qty2, d.qty3, d.qty4, d.qty5, ..., d.qty20,
       ( SELECT MIN(NULLIF(q.qty, 0)) 
         FROM 
           ( SELECT d.qty2 AS qty UNION ALL
             SELECT d.qty3 UNION ALL
             ...
             SELECT d.qty20
           ) AS q
       ) AS MinVal, 
       ( SELECT MAX(q.qty) 
         FROM 
           ( SELECT d.qty2 AS qty UNION ALL
             SELECT d.qty3 UNION ALL
             ...
             SELECT d.qty20
           ) AS q
       ) AS MaxVal 
FROM 
    dummydata AS d ;
```

Tested in [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/LHHTX52350)

Comment: i Have edited my question with create table for more clarification . as you their is no PK  in my table and your second query it gives min,max values which are not in rows  ..

Comment: No PK and no UNIQUE constraint?

Comment: Can you share us with 2-3 sample rows and the wrong output? This seems weird.

Comment: hii .. I have edited my question image that shows output of your query .

Comment: and last two are MinValue and MaxValue

Comment: This is from my second query? Notice that in my second query, there are no `FROM` clauses in the subquery, only in the main query.

Comment: I tested (not in 2000) but in more recent version: http://rextester.com/KTTEK32056 and works as expected.

Comment: @speedyraz Are you sure you used the same query as my suggestion, without any modification?

Comment: thanks for your all efforts , I found working query from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166225/get-max-and-min-values-of-each-rows-in-sql-server
Thanks again .......

Comment: Good that you found a solution. The answer there is similar to my 2nd query (just uses `TOP 1` instead of `MAX()`.) I can't see why both ways shouldn't work. They only differ on how they handle NULL values but I assumed that you want to ignore nulls and 0s.